# JS Object Array Remove last empty element

Tags: javascript, object

I have that javascript object :

```
MyObject = [
   {
     "name" : "aaa",
     "firstname" : "aaaaa"
   },
   {
     "name" : "bbb",
     "firstname" : "bbbb"
   },
   {
     "name" : "cccc",
     "firstname" : "" <--------- firstname is empty, but the element is not in the last
   },
   {
     "name" : "ddd",
     "firstname" : "dddd"
   },
   {
     "name" : "eeee",
     "firstname" : ""  <--------- firstname is empty
   },
   {
     "name" : "fffff",
     "firstname" : ""  <--------- firstname is empty
   },
]
```

I want to delete the **lastest lines** that have "firstname" empty ... (a sort of trim) ... i dont want to remove all lines that have "firstname" empty... but just who are in the latestes lines. (that are in the bottom)

So, the result will be :

```
MyObject = [
   {
     "name" : "aaa",
     "firstname" : "aaaaa"
   },
   {
     "name" : "bbb",
     "firstname" : "bbbb"
   },
   {
     "name" : "cccc",
     "firstname" : ""
   },
   {
     "name" : "ddd",
     "firstname" : "dddd"
   }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: How you define "lastest"?

Answer (score 1):

You can pop of at the end of the array as long as the firstname is empty

```js
var MyObject = [{
    "name": "aaa",
    "firstname": "aaaaa"
}, {
    "name": "bbb",
    "firstname": "bbbb"
}, {
    "name": "cccc",
    "firstname": ""
}, {
    "name": "ddd",
    "firstname": "dddd"
}, {
    "name": "eeee",
    "firstname": ""
}, {
    "name": "fffff",
    "firstname": ""
}];

for (var i=MyObject.length;i--;) if (MyObject[i].firstname==="") MyObject.pop(); else break;

console.log(MyObject)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top: 0!important;}
```

Comment: It didn't remove item `"name": "eeee"`

Comment: @jcubic - I assumed *"the lastest lines"* was just the last item. I think I misunderstood that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var MyObject = [
   {
     "name" : "aaa",
     "firstname" : "aaaaa"
   },
   {
     "name" : "bbb",
     "firstname" : "bbbb"
   },
   {
     "name" : "cccc",
     "firstname" : ""
   },
   {
     "name" : "ddd",
     "firstname" : "dddd"
   },
   {
     "name" : "eeee",
     "firstname" : ""
   },
   {
     "name" : "fffff",
     "firstname" : ""
   }
];
var i = MyObject.length;
while(true) {
  if (!MyObject[--i].firstname) {
    MyObject.pop();
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(MyObject);
```